# Override view function android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to support game controller input in my app, I should be able to receive the input when in focus of any element of the app. By the way it is not a game.
I have tried following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input) guide from the android developer documentation to no avail.
The problem I am facing is that I cannot override the onKeyDown function.

My only knowledge is that I need to override this function in either a custom view or activity, but this is what I am having trouble with.

Here is the sort of code I am attempting.

```
class customView(context:Context) : View(context){
    override fun onKeyDown(...){
        // Code to handle keydown

    }
}
```

I am getting an error saying something about onKeyDown not being a method of the view class (sorry I'm not at my computer at the moment so I don't know the exact error)

Just as another note I have also looked at [this about custom views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view) and I don't really understand how I should go about implementing controller input. For example if I was to create a new view, I would prefer to override something like a fragment which would allow me to have controller input across the entire app. Would it work better overriding the activity?

I'm new to android and kotlin development, so I'm sorry if this is really simple.

Thanks

Comment: What parameters do you have  because it takes parameters of `keyCode: Int,event: KeyEvent`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: I have been using the parameters from the documentation, but it still doesn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong in the XML file referencing. Please could someone give an example of an XML file referencing the view. Will this work listening for controller events even when the focus changes to other views or not?

Comment: Tip: when you want to override something, press Ctrl+O and select the function from the list. The IDE will fill out the skeleton of the function for you with the correct signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the return type

```
class customView(context: Context) : View(context) {

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

To answer your question in the comments, in order to add this view to an XML layout your would need to do something like this

```
<package.of.my.costumview.customView   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Comment: Ok I will try this when I can. My IDE shows a red line under override as if there is no onKeyDown method in view. Please could you let me know how I would get this to work in the XML file, I am having difficulty with that as well.

Comment: The IDE is correct, there is no `onKeyDown` method with a return type of `Void` on the `View class`. I don't know what you mean by working on the XML file, could you explain this better?

Comment: Ok thank you I will try adding the correct return type. I mean the XML file for the android layout, as in the GUI. Should the view be defined in the XML file for the layout and how would I do this properly?

Comment: Oh! I see, to add this view to an XML file you need to use reference the package of your custom view, I will edit my answer to explain it better

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.

Comment: I edited my question, I think this was what you ask for, let me know if you were successful

Comment: This should be working. I'm getting no errors in my IDE but my build fails when I add the class to my view. Here is my log https://pastebin.com/pv2sMqG5, my code for the class https://pastebin.com/x7ZFaVKr and my code for the xml layout https://pastebin.com/dgyjxzyn. The class is called ViewController by the way. I think the error could either be the formatting of my xml layout or am I supposed to inflate the layout from within the ViewController class?

Comment: Just to add, this is my main activity file https://pastebin.com/MxDNfBWG and FirstFragment https://pastebin.com/U3p6p6PA. I am using the default sample basic activity at the moment so there shouldn't be any errors in other code that could be conflicting with this.

Comment: I'm on my phone, it's hard to check but it looks like you are missing constructors, press Alt - Insert  and click in Constructors to add them.

Comment: I have managed to get it working now, the crashing of my app has stopped after adding attributeSet to the constructor. However, I am still not getting any input from the controller. In the documentation it says it must be a focused view, so I will try it with an activity instead. I'll mark this as solved though because I'm not getting any errors now. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I never worked with controllers, maybe try setting  `android:clickable="true"` `android:focusable="true"` in your custom view

Comment: Ah, now it works after adding that. Thanks. Definitely solved now.